# Why doesn't the formula for the PMF on geometric distributions make use of ${\mathbb N}$?

Tags: probability-theory

If you look online you'll find that the formula for the PMF on geometric distributions looks like this: 
${\displaystyle \Pr(X=k)=(1-p)^{k-1}p}$
for $k = 1, 2, 3... $ 
Why don't people just write
$k, {k \in \mathbb N}$

Comment: Firstly, this looks like a geometric distribution. Secondly, they are called probability mass functions. Thirdly, there is some ambiguity on whether $\mathbb N$ includes 0 or not.

Comment: To exclude $0$ I prefer to write $k\in \mathbb N^\color{blue}+$. Beside this, you can use that.

Comment: Geometric distribution represent the first time you can see something happening. Say if you have $(X_n)$ a sequence of random variable independent and distributed according to the binomial law of parameter $p$, then $Y = \inf \left\lbrace n : X_n = 1 \right\rbrace$ follows a geometrical law of parameter $p$. The $(X_n)$ are see as observations and their enumeration may naturally start at $1$.

Comment: @Gregory Isn't  ${\mathbb  {N}}^{*} $ used to include 0?

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the mistake

Comment: Possibly. I'm not aware of that syntax, but that doesn't mean anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason people write $k=1,2,3,\dots$ instead of $k\in \mathbb N$ is because there is no consensus about whether $\mathbb N=\{1,2,\dots\}$ or $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\dots\}$. The potential for confusion is especially high with the geometric distribution, because some people define it like you did, while others define the geometric distribution by
$$
P(Y=k)=(1-p)p^k,\qquad k=0,1,2,\dots
$$
Both conventions appear on the Wikipedia page side by side. Just looking at the $k\in \mathbb N$ part, you would have to know which convention for $\mathbb N$ the author was using to know which geometric distribution condition they were using.

<sup>(I personally prefer $0\in \mathbb N$. Anyone who works with power series a lot may agree, since powers of $x$ can be any nonnegative integer. Furthermore, if the natural numbers are for counting, and you want to count the number of elements of a finite set, then zero is a possible answer!)</sup>